# Is there a way to manipulate a icon file with Python?

Tags: python, windows-xp, icons, python-2.5

Ok, so I have Python 2.5 with Windows XP. I want to create a program that will create and/or manipulate an icon (.ico) file. Is there any module that can do this? Thanks.

EDIT:

I will need to save the image back into a .ico file.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/45507/is-there-a-python-library-for-generating-ico-files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the [Python Image Library](http://www.pythonware.com/products/pil/) or PIL for short. Also, take a look at this plug in for PIL that makes it handle images correctly on windows: http://code.google.com/p/casadebender/wiki/Win32IconImagePlugin

There is also this: [pythonMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/download/python/)

Comment: I checked man, it can only read Icon (.ico) files. Not edit/create them.

Comment: you might want to try to create a PNG or some other format, manipulate it with PIL, then convert it to .ico with imageMagick.