# Resize rectangular image to square, keeping ratio and fill background with black

Tags: python, opencv, numpy, image-processing, python-imaging-library

I'm trying to resize a batch of grayscale images that are 256 x N pixels (N varies, but is always ≤256).

My intention is to downscale the images.

The resize would have to output a square (1:1) image, with:

- resized image centered vertically
- aspect ratio maintained
- remaining pixels rendered black

Visually this would be the desired result:

[image]

I have tried creating a numpy zeroes matrix with the target size (e.g. 200 x 200) but have not been able to paste the resized image into its vertical center.

Any suggestions using cv2, PIL or numpy are welcome.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

You can use [`Pillow`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zOjCO.png) to accomplish that:

#### Code:

```
from PIL import Image

def make_square(im, min_size=256, fill_color=(0, 0, 0, 0)):
    x, y = im.size
    size = max(min_size, x, y)
    new_im = Image.new('RGBA', (size, size), fill_color)
    new_im.paste(im, (int((size - x) / 2), int((size - y) / 2)))
    return new_im
```

#### Test Code:

```
test_image = Image.open('hLarp.png')
new_image = make_square(test_image)
new_image.show()
```

For a white background you can do:

```
new_image = make_square(test_image, fill_color=(255, 255, 255, 0))
```

#### Result:

[image]

Comment: this looks really good, thanks—so the origin in `.paste` will be at the center?

Comment: centered, unless the image is an odd number of pixels.

Comment: Sure - caught it because I just used it.

Comment: this code only resize the background into min_size and put the original image into it centered. How to resize the original image into min_size? thanks.

Comment: I tried using it on jupyter notebook with python 3 and I had to convert *(size - x) / 2* and *(size - y) / 2* to int using *int((size - x) / 2)* and *int((size - x) / 2)*. Also I had to change RGBA to RGB to get the black background

Comment: @sliawatimena you can put ***min_size = x if x > y else y*** in the method _make_square_ and it should do the trick

Comment: Is it possible to make the background transparent somehow?

Comment: @wannabeprogrammer https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/handbook/tutorial.html#rolling-an-image

Answer (score 10):

Here is a code that solve your question with OPENCV module (using NUMPY module too)

```
#Importing modules opencv + numpy
import cv2
import numpy as np

#Reading an image (you can use PNG or JPG)
img = cv2.imread("image.png")

#Getting the bigger side of the image
s = max(img.shape[0:2])

#Creating a dark square with NUMPY  
f = np.zeros((s,s,3),np.uint8)

#Getting the centering position
ax,ay = (s - img.shape[1])//2,(s - img.shape[0])//2

#Pasting the 'image' in a centering position
f[ay:img.shape[0]+ay,ax:ax+img.shape[1]] = img

#Showing results (just in case) 
cv2.imshow("IMG",f)
#A pause, waiting for any press in keyboard
cv2.waitKey(0)

#Saving the image
cv2.imwrite("img2square.png",f)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Is it possible to create a square with a transparent background by `.zeros` method?

Answer (score 8):

[PIL.ImageOps.pad](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/ImageOps.html#PIL.ImageOps.pad):

```
from PIL import Image, ImageOps

with Image.open('hLARP.png') as im:
    im = ImageOps.pad(im, (200, 200), color='black')
im.save('result.png')
```

Answer (score 3):

PIL has the thumbnail method which will scale keeping the aspect ratio.  From there you just need to paste it centered onto your black background rectangle.

```
from PIL import Image

def black_background_thumbnail(path_to_image, thumbnail_size=(200,200)):
    background = Image.new('RGBA', thumbnail_size, "black")    
    source_image = Image.open(path_to_image).convert("RGBA")
    source_image.thumbnail(thumbnail_size)
    (w, h) = source_image.size
    background.paste(source_image, ((thumbnail_size[0] - w) / 2, (thumbnail_size[1] - h) / 2 ))
    return background

if __name__ == '__main__':
    img = black_background_thumbnail('hLARP.png')
    img.save('tmp.jpg')
    img.show()
```

Answer (score 2):

```
from PIL import Image

def reshape(image):
    '''
    Reshapes the non-square image by pasting
    it to the centre of a black canvas of size
    n*n where n is the biggest dimension of
    the non-square image. 
    '''
    old_size = image.size
    max_dimension, min_dimension = max(old_size), min(old_size)
    desired_size = (max_dimension, max_dimension)
    position = int(max_dimension/2) - int(min_dimension/2) 
    blank_image = Image.new("RGB", desired_size, color='black')
    if image.height<image.width:
        blank_image.paste(image, (0, position))
    else:
        blank_image.paste(image, (position, 0))
    return blank_image
```

Answer (score 2):

Behold! A greatly-overengineered version of @Stepeh Rauch's answer that contains an interactive element and accounts for odd-pixel padding.

[image]

### Usage

```
# Note: PySide2 can also be replaced by PyQt5, PyQt6, PySide6
# Also note! Any of the above are >100MB
pip install utilitys pyside2 pillow
$ python <file.py> --help
usage: <file>.py [-h] [--folder FOLDER] [--ext EXT]

optional arguments:
  -h, --help       show this help message and exit
  --folder FOLDER  Folder of images allowed for viewing. Must have at least one image (default: .)
  --ext EXT        Image extension to look for (default: png)

$ python <file>.py --folder "./path/to/folder/of/your/image(s).png" --ext "jpg"
```

### `file.py` contents

```py
import argparse
from pathlib import Path
from typing import Tuple, Union, Any

import numpy as np
import pyqtgraph as pg
from PIL import Image
from utilitys import fns, widgets, RunOpts


def pad_to_size(
    image: Image.Image,
    size_wh: Union[int, Tuple[int, int]] = None,
    fill_color: Any = 0,
    **resize_kwargs,
) -> Image.Image:
    """
    Keeps an image's aspect ratio by resizing until the largest side is constrained
    by the specified output size. Then, the deficient dimension is padded until
    the image is the specified size.
    """
    if size_wh is None:
        size_wh = max(image.size)

    if isinstance(size_wh, int):
        size_wh = (size_wh, size_wh)

    im_size_wh = np.array(image.size)
    ratios = im_size_wh / size_wh

    # Resize until the largest side is constrained by the specified output size
    im_size_wh = np.ceil(im_size_wh / ratios.max()).astype(int)
    # Prefer 1-pixel difference in aspect ratio vs. odd padding
    pad_amt = np.array(size_wh) - im_size_wh
    use_ratio_idx = np.argmax(ratios)
    unused_ratio_idx = 1 - use_ratio_idx

    # Sanity check for floating point accuracy: At least one side must match
    # user-requested dimension
    if np.all(pad_amt != 0):
        # Adjust dimension that is supposed to match
        im_size_wh[use_ratio_idx] += pad_amt[use_ratio_idx]
    # Prefer skewing aspect ratio by 1 pixel instead of odd padding
    # If odd, 1 will be added. Otherwise, the dimension remains unchanged
    im_size_wh[unused_ratio_idx] += pad_amt[unused_ratio_idx] % 2
    image = image.resize(tuple(im_size_wh), **resize_kwargs)

    new_im = Image.new("RGB", size_wh, fill_color)
    width, height = image.size
    new_im.paste(image, (int((size_wh[0] - width) / 2), int((size_wh[1] - height) / 2)))
    return new_im


def main(folder=".", ext="png"):
    """
    Parameters
    ----------
    folder: str, Path
        Folder of images allowed for viewing. Must have at least one image
    ext: str, Path
        Image extension to look for

    """
    folder = Path(folder)
    files = fns.naturalSorted(folder.glob(f"*.{ext}"))
    err_msg = f"{folder} must have at least one image file with extension `{ext}`"
    assert len(files), err_msg

    pg.mkQApp()
    viewer = widgets.ImageViewer()

    def readim(file_index=0, try_pad=False, output_w=512, output_h=512):
        if 0 > file_index > len(files):
            return
        image = Image.open(files[file_index])
        if try_pad:
            image = pad_to_size(image, (output_w, output_h), fill_color=(255, 255, 255))
        viewer.setImage(np.array(image))

    viewer.toolsEditor.registerFunc(readim, runOpts=RunOpts.ON_CHANGED)
    wc = viewer.widgetContainer()
    readim()
    wc.show()
    pg.exec()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Print defaults in help signature
    fmt = dict(formatter_class=argparse.ArgumentDefaultsHelpFormatter)
    cli = fns.makeCli(main, parserKwargs=fmt)
    args = cli.parse_args()
    main(**vars(args))
```