# Python3: Resize rectangular image to a different kind of rectangle, keeping ratio and fill background with black

Tags: python, python-3.x, image

I have a very similar question to this: [Resize rectangular image to square, keeping ratio and fill background with black](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44231209/resize-rectangular-image-to-square-keeping-ratio-and-fill-background-with-black?rq=1), but I would like to resize to a nonsquare image and center the image either horizontally or vertically if needed.

Here are some examples of desired outputs. I made this image entirely with Paint, so the images might not actually be perfectly centered, but centering is what I'd like to achieve:

[image: desired outputs]

I tried the following code that I edited from the question linked:

```
def fix_size(fn, desired_w=256, desired_h=256, fill_color=(0, 0, 0, 255)):
    """Edited from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44231209/resize-rectangular-image-to-square-keeping-ratio-and-fill-background-with-black"""
    im = Image.open(fn)
    x, y = im.size
    #size = max(min_size, x, y)
    w = max(desired_w, x)
    h = max(desired_h, y)
    new_im = Image.new('RGBA', (w, h), fill_color)
    new_im.paste(im, ((w - x) // 2, (h - y) // 2))
    return new_im.resize((desired_w, desired_h))
```

That doesn't work however as it still stretches some images into square shaped ones (at least the image b in the example. What comes to big images, it seems to rotate them instead!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem lies in your incorrect calculation of the image size:

```
w = max(desired_w, x)
h = max(desired_h, y)
```

You're simply taking the maximum of dimension independently - without taking into account the aspect ratio of the image. Imagine if your input is a square 1000x1000 image. You would end up creating a black 1000x1000 image, pasting the original image over it, and then resizing it to 244x138. To get the correct result, you would have to create a 1768x1000 image instead of a 1000x1000 image.

---

Here's the updated code that takes the aspect ratio into account:

```
def fix_size(fn, desired_w=256, desired_h=256, fill_color=(0, 0, 0, 255)):
    """Edited from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44231209/resize-rectangular-image-to-square-keeping-ratio-and-fill-background-with-black"""
    im = Image.open(fn)
    x, y = im.size

    ratio = x / y
    desired_ratio = desired_w / desired_h

    w = max(desired_w, x)
    h = int(w / desired_ratio)
    if h < y:
        h = y
        w = int(h * desired_ratio)

    new_im = Image.new('RGBA', (w, h), fill_color)
    new_im.paste(im, ((w - x) // 2, (h - y) // 2))
    return new_im.resize((desired_w, desired_h))
```

Comment: That unfortunately doesn't work for me. For the image in b), it does exactly the same as the command Image.open('image.png').resize((244, 138)).save('image2.png') .

For a bigger JPG image (3456x5184 with desired_w 5184 and desired_h 3456, similar to example b but with a lot bigger images in JPG format), it stretches and rotates, while my original code just rotates. Neither is what I want, I don't want to stretch nor rotate, but the codes do it anyway :(   -- (By 'stretch' I mean change aspect ratio of the original not-necessarily-black part of the image)

Comment: @hilssu Whoops. I guess I should've tested it on more images. My bad. I think/hope it's fixed now :)

Comment: Yep, thanks, that worked! Well, it in fact did rotate one JPG image taken with my friend's camera, but when I opened it with Paint and saved it as another JPG file, it worked fine. This proves that JPG images can be encoded in at least two different ways, at least one of which PIL can't handle correctly.

Comment: @hilssu Yes, there are ways to store rotation information in image metadata; I suspect that PIL ignores that.