# How to resize a square image to rectangle with white borders in Python

Tags: python, image-processing, python-imaging-library

I have many 708x708 pictures which I need to resize into a 500x250px, keeping the ratio the same. I imagined this can be done by resize the actual image to 250x250 via `Image.thumbnail('image.jpg')`, and adding two white borders to fill the remainder of the space. However, I don't know how to do the latter. The following code gives me the thumbnail image of 250x250px.

```
image = img
img
image.thumbnail((500, 250))
image.save('image_thumbnail.jpg')

print(image.size)
```

Question is similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44231209/resize-rectangular-image-to-square-keeping-ratio-and-fill-background-with-black/44231784).

Any suggestions would be much appreciated!

Comment: Do you just want to resize it or also add the white borders?

Comment: I want to resize the picture from 708x708 to a 250x250 (thumbnail) and add a white border on top and below the picture to make it a 500x250.

Comment: @Liri Read about [PIL.Image.new](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.new) and [PIL.Image.Image.paste](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html?highlight=paste#PIL.Image.Image.paste), [PIL.Image.merge](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.merge),  [PIL.ImageOps.expand](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/ImageOps.html#PIL.ImageOps.expand)

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread('myimage.jpg', cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)

print('Original Dimensions : ',img.shape)

width = int(img.shape[1] * 35.31 / 100) # 250/708 is 35%
height = int(img.shape[0] * 35.31 / 100)
dim = (width, height)
resized_image = cv2.resize(img, dim, interpolation = cv2.INTER_AREA)

print('Resized_image Dimensions : ',resized_image.shape)


row, col = resized_image.shape[:2]
bottom = resized_image[row-2:row, 0:col]

bordersize = 125
border = cv2.copyMakeBorder(
    resized_image,
    top=bordersize,
    bottom=bordersize,
    left=0,
    right=0,
    borderType=cv2.BORDER_CONSTANT,
    value=[255, 255, 255]
)

cv2.imshow('image', resized_image)
cv2.imshow('left', bottom)
cv2.imshow('right', border)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: The code just reorients the image, it doesn't resize it as requested.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the following: first, I make a thumbnail of size (250,250) and alter the image with `ImageOps.expand` to add two white borders to make the dimensions (250, 250).

```
from PIL import Image, ImageOps
img = Image.open('801595.jpg')
img.thumbnail((500, 250))
print(img.size)
img_with_border = ImageOps.expand(img, border = (125, 0) ,fill='white')
img_with_border.save('imaged-with-border2.jpg')
```

Answer (score -1):

Check this [method](https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.transform.html#skimage.transform.resize) in `skimage` package. There's parameter called `mode`, where you can control desired behaviour.

Comment: No mode does that.